# Read images in loop, wait for their load

Tags: javascript, loops

**No jQuery**

So, I need a function which checks all images on page in loop. I need to get their dimensions and to validate these.

```
function checkImageInputs() {
    var images = new Array();
    var fileInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');

    for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
        var t = fileInputs[i];
        var ourCell = t.parentNode;

        if (t.files[0]) {
            var file = t.files[0];

            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = createImage;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);

            function createImage() { // Create Image
                img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = fr.result;
                img.className = 'file-result';
                ourCell.appendChild(img);
                images[i] = img;
            }
        }
    }

    // I need the images array here
    alert(images.length);
}
```

When I added the loop to my function to work with all the file-inputs on page, it doesn't return to me the wanted result.

The `alert` returns 0, even if all my file-inputs are filled up with images.

The `fr.onload` does his functionality later, after `alert`.
The same is for the `ourCell.appendChild(img)`, the image appears after `alert`.

How to make that `alert` to show the real number of images, to wait until all the images are loaded?

I call this function on DOM load like this:

```
var fileInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');
for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
    fileInputs[i].onchange = new Function('checkImageInputs()');
}
```

Comment: `1` You seem to have forgotten to `var` some of your variables, `2` rather than using _FileReader_, make use of the fact _File_ inherits from _Blob_, call [`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) on it. This saves you a lot of time and effort. `3` you can't `alert` there - it is before the asynchronous code has completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is async, so your length evaluation statement is executed before the createImage callbacks are executed. One more thing i noticed is that you are setting the values to the array `images` with the loop iteration variable within which you have a condition. So anything that doesn't match a condition will create a hole in the array at that index so the length of the array will not reflect the actual number of items in the array. So use array.push instead and better use Array literal rather than the array constructor. This is unless you really want to know if an image is present or not.

So try this way:

```
function checkImageInputs(callback) { //take a callback argument
    var images = [],
       fileInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input'),
       left = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
        var t = fileInputs[i];
        var ourCell = t.parentNode;

        if (t.files[0]) {
            var file = t.files[0];
            left++; //increment the count
            var fr = new FileReader(); //If you don't specify a var keyword here fr becomes global
            fr.onload = createImage.bind(this, i); //bind the iteration variable here
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);

            function createImage(itr) { // Create Image
                var img = document.createElement('img'); //If you don't specify a var keyword here img becomes global
                img.src = fr.result;
                img.className = 'file-result';
                ourCell.appendChild(img);
                images.push(img);
                left--; //decrement left count
                if(!left) { //check if this is the last one
                  callback(images); //now make the call back
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

function postProcess(images){
    // I need the images array here
    alert(images.length);
}

checkImageInputs(postProcess); //provide the callback as argument here.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubryG/)**

One solution uses ecmaScript5 to [function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the loop iteration variable to the function which is not availabe in earlier browsers but you can alsways patch ith with the script mentioned in the link. other option replace it with a closure.

change

```
fr.onload = createImage.bind(this, i);
```

to

```
fr.onload = (function(i){
            return function(){
                createImage(i);
            }              
        })(i);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwqF7/)**

Comment: I'm not sure that will work, as the file is only loaded `if (t.files[0])`. So you could actually be waiting for more images than will ever be loaded. Or the callback will never be called if the last `fileInput` is not used.

Comment: @PaulGrime In that case he can lock use a counter inside creatImage increment it for each callback exeution and compare that instead of i. Also this is an option he can use, I am not writing to cover all scenarios, this can help OP write it himself.

Comment: Sure I understand. Can help to point out some of the potential difficulties though.

Comment: Updated the answer with closure option as well incase bind doen't work for you.

Comment: It works, but not always. When I load the page and add one image, it doesn't alert anything, only if I add one more image in my second input, it alerts 2.

Comment: Your Feedle works the same, only when 2 images are put, it alerts.

Comment: See my comment. The solution relies on all the `fileInputs` having a valid value.

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR Think about your for loop it iterated through all and inside that in the callback we have check when to call the callback.. Its a clue for you to figure out... :)

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR Anyways i leave it for you to figure out. If worst case refer to this.. http://jsfiddle.net/22can/ :)